# Most (but not all) Java Flyway migrations are skipped

Tags: flyway

The symptom of the problem is 3 fold, with gradle:
- flywayMigrate fails with org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.1
- flywayInfo reports numerous migrations as Missing, basically all the JDBC migrations.

```
Versioned   1.0 create initial db   SQL 2013-04-05 10:49:18 Success
Versioned   1.1 InsertEnum  JDBC    2013-04-05 10:49:18 Missing
Versioned   1.2 InsertDefaultCampaign   JDBC    2013-04-05 10:49:18  Missing
```

While actually at a DB level, the schema_version tables reports them as

```
2   2   1.0 create initial db   SQL V1_0__create_initial_db.sql 1924949074  ACCTESTING  05-APR-13 10.49.18.288446000 AM 1843    1
3   3   1.1 InsertEnum  JDBC    cern.acctesting.db.migrations.base.V1_1__InsertEnum     ACCTESTING  05-APR-13 10.49.18.486188000 AM 95  1
4   4   1.2 InsertDefaultCampaign   JDBC    cern.acctesting.db.migrations.base.V1_2__InsertDefaultCampaign      ACCTESTING  05-APR-13 10.49.18.652105000 AM 83  1
```

- logs from the task report that these classes are found:

```
13:43:01.219 [QUIET] [system.out] [DEBUG] - Found class: cern.acctesting.db.migrations.base.V1_1__InsertEnum
13:43:01.220 [QUIET] [system.out] [DEBUG] - Found class: cern.acctesting.db.migrations.base.V1_2__InsertDefaultCampaign
```

On the other hand, numerous other classes are skipped:

```
13:43:01.265 [QUIET] [system.out] [DEBUG] - Skipping non-instantiable class (invocation error): cern.acctesting.db.migrations.content.V2_3_2__CreateTestPhaseAndSignOnlyTestsForBeamLossMonitors
```

there is no fundamental difference in the class structure.

I've a database that executed multiple migrations up to 3.5.2 in the past. It was running on Oracle 11g with Flyway 3.1. I'm now upgrading everything to Oracle 18c and Flyway 5.2.4. I'm using gradle 4.9 and the plugin flyway-gradle-plugin:5.2.4

Note maybe related or not to the problem, I had to manually edit the schema_version table to change the Type INIT to BASELINE (as well as the corresponding checksum).

I tried to remove all deprecation adapting all my migration classes to the 5.2.4 BaseJavaMigration, without success.

I then tried to use the flyway command line 5.2.4, building a jar from my IDE where I ran Gradle and using it in the CLI. Then I got more confused:

```
Versioned   1.0 create initial db   SQL 2013-04-05 10:49:18 Success
Versioned   1.1 InsertEnum  JDBC    2013-04-05 10:49:18 Success
Versioned   1.2 InsertDefaultCampaign   JDBC    2013-04-05 10:49:18 Missing
```

I tried to reproduce the issue locally, executing in a unit test similar code to what flyway does. I couldn't reproduce the issue.
I've been running gradle in debug mode and no-daemon to attach a debugger and see how the class was loaded. I didn't spot anything wrong... it relies on a URLClassLoader that contains the entire classpath and it seems correct.

There is no fundamental difference between migration 1.1 and 1.2

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class V1_1__InsertEnum implements JdbcMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
        insertTestStepStates(connection);
        insertSignatureTypes(connection);
        insertLocktype(connection);
    }

    /// some private method definitions
}
```

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class V1_2__InsertDefaultCampaign implements JdbcMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
        long campaignId = getCampaignId(connection);
        insertDefaultCampaign(connection, campaignId);
        insertDefaultTestPlan(connection, campaignId);
        insertActiveCampaign(connection, campaignId);
    }

    /// some private method definitions
}
```

I had them ported to extend the BaseJavaMigration, or even to implement the JavaMigration myself. It changed nothing.

So here are my current observations and problems: 
- for the same code, I've an inconsistent behavior between the flyway command line tool and the gradle flyway plugin, both version 5.2.4
- most of my classes are not loadable by Flyway and I've no idea why
- the loaded classes are anyway not resolved locally and I've no idea why

Maybe I'm missing something super obvious and digging too deep for nothing?
Any idea what's wrong?